# How to change the colors of items conditionally in Kendo treeview

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview

I am using first time Kendo ui so I have very limited knowledge about it. What should I do to change treeview items color for some conditions.

```
<div>
    @(          
    Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                .Name("treeview")
                .TemplateId("treeviewTemp")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "rightlist"})
                .BindTo((IEnumerable<NavigationViewModel>)ViewBag.Tree, (NavigationBindingFactory<TreeViewItem> mappings) =>
                {
                mappings.For<NavigationViewModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, node) =>              
                {
                item.Text = node.Description;

                    }).Children(node => node.Children));

                    mappings.For<NavigationViewModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, subCategory) =>
                    { item.Text = subCategory.Description; }));
                })
          )
</div>
```

And this is the templete. Template works for color change but tree items comes as "undefined". Is it also possible to add some conditions in script?

```
<script id="treeviewTemp" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    <div>
        <span style="color: Green">#: item.Text #</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086392/how-to-set-the-tree-view-node-color-for-kendo-ui-treeview

Comment: First of all, paste your code in the question's body instead of a screenshot of it; Now, about the problem, you already have defined `treeviewTemp` as template, can you add it to your question ?

Comment: Thank you for correction, I am new here and just learning